# Docker container works well, but Singularity sif creates permission error

Tags: docker, file-permissions, singularity-container, apptainer

I created a Docker image that works as expected. I've provided the dockerfile and entrypoint file [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1l5UccCUpVoFlB5JGZuMdUbgjkZ2mymz7?usp=sharing) on the off chance it's helpful.

I can run through `prokaregia.sh`, the script the environment was designed to run, as expected with the following command:

```html
sudo docker run prokaregia_v2:latest /workflow/prokaregia.sh -i prokaregia.sh -s ont
```

(I'm not sure why I need to provide the `workflow` directory given that I included `WORKDIR /workflow` in the dockerfile, so if anyone has any ideas let me know!)

I then built that container into a .sif file using the following command:

```html
sudo apptainer build prokaregia_v2.sif docker-daemon://local/prokaregia_v2:latest
```

However, giving the resulting image what I believe is the equivalent command:

```html
apptainer run prokaregia_v2.sif /workflow/prokaregia.sh -i prokaregia.sh -s ont
```

Yields the following error:

```html
/workflow/entrypoint.sh: line 7: /workflow/prokaregia.sh: Permission denied
/workflow/entrypoint.sh: line 7: exec: /workflow/prokaregia.sh: cannot execute: Permission denied
```

Running with `exec` rather than `run` produces a similar error: `FATAL: permission denied`

I've tried running `apptainer shell prokaregia_v2.sif` to manually change the permissions, but the directory structure is identical to the directory that I used to create the Docker container, not to the directory structure I'd expect to find inside the container. Inside the directory structure revealed this way is a file named `prokaregia_v2.sif`, but it isn't a directory I can change to in order to operate inside of, which is sort of what I expected. Changing permissions on the files in there has no effect on the above error. Sudo doesn't change anything. Any ideas on what might be causing the problem?